# Apache Tomcat Access Error: 404 -- Not Found

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I use to run my WAR files in webapps as follows

- Run the CATALINA.bat start using the command prompt (After navigating
  into the bin folder) Server Startup is successful as before.
- after running the CATALINA.bat in my Browser I go into
  `http://localhost:8080/` where I normally find my App in Manage Apps.
- But suddenly now I get "Access Error: 404 -- Not Found" Error and I
  have no idea of solving it. What should I do?

Localhost.2014-02-03.log

```
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1d30479')
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@dddee8')
```

Catalina Log

```
Feb 03, 2014 8:18:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.4.8.
Feb 03, 2014 8:18:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Feb 03, 2014 8:18:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:623)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:640)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

Feb 03, 2014 8:19:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:640)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:623)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    ... 13 more

Feb 03, 2014 8:19:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 11754 ms
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\CricManager.war
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:09 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [647] milliseconds.
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\docs
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\examples
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\host-manager
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\manager
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\ROOT
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Feb 03, 2014 8:19:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10995 ms
Feb 03, 2014 8:22:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Feb 03, 2014 8:22:07 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.4.8.
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:623)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:640)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

Feb 03, 2014 8:23:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:640)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:623)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    ... 13 more

Feb 03, 2014 8:23:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1715 ms
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\CricManager.war
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\docs
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\examples
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\host-manager
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\manager
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\ROOT
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Feb 03, 2014 8:23:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2071 ms
```

Comment: Have you looked into logs ? Are you sure about the port number etc ?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of the server log? 404 only tells us that something's missing.

Comment: Which Log should I send? Catalina Log or Localhost or Localhost_Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WAR` may not be deployed correctly. Check `catalina.out` log file for errors. Also to debug clean the folder `work` then call `startup.bat` and see if you war is exploded in the `work` directory.

**Edit:**

Try killing all Tomcat instances, you should have one still running.

Comment: There were no log by catalina.out, I cleaned and deployed again, No luck yet :(

Comment: Try to kill all JVM instances (java.exe in the task manager), something is running on port 8080 (must be an old Tomcat instance).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log you have more than one instance of tomcat running. Kill the other instance and try again